# The fastest way to find highest number in document

Tags: c#, winforms

I have got file which looks like this:

```
[...]
UTS+48:::{7}:{8}+{9}'
UTB+454343::34343+{10}-{12}'
[...]
```

After choosing file in my Form, I read whole file into a single string. Now, I need to find the highest number between these brackets {}. What will be the best solution for that? I have already solved that, but my solution isn't the best in my opinion. I was thinking about using some Regex but I honsetly don't know how to use it properly.

Here is my solution:

```
private int GetNumberOfParameters(string text)
{
    string temp = File.ReadAllText(text);
    string number = String.Empty, highestNumber = String.Empty;
    bool firstNumber = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length; i++)
    {
        if (temp[i].Equals('{'))
        {
            int j = i;
            j++;
            while (!temp[j].Equals('}'))
            {
                number += temp[j];
                j++;
            }

            if (firstNumber)
            {
                highestNumber = number;
                number = String.Empty;
                firstNumber = false;
            }
            else if (Int16.Parse(number) > Int16.Parse(highestNumber))
            {
                highestNumber = number;
                number = String.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                number = String.Empty;
            }

        }
    }
    if (highestNumber.Equals(String.Empty))
        return 0;
    else
        return Int16.Parse(highestNumber);
}
```

Comment: What is your solution?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/sGTurxqP here is my solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following regex to extract number strings between `{` and `}` brackets.

```
(?<={)\d+(?=})
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Then you convert extracted strings into numbers and find the maximum one.

Sample code:

```
string s = "{5} + {666}";
long max = Regex.Matches(s, @"(?<={)\d+(?=})")
                .Cast<Match>()
                .Select(m => long.Parse(m.Value))
                .Max();
```

Comment: Cool visualization of the RegEx, is that a tool you can link me to ?

Comment: It is great! I wanted to do something like that, but I just didn't know how to use it like you have used. Thank you very much!